# Emails backed up on external hard-drive, how do I transfer those emails into a new gmail account?

Tags: email, backup, gmail

My customers are very old-school and I have finally convinced them to switch to G-Suite, however now they want all their old emails uploaded to the new gmail account.

Comment: GSuite has a tool for this, check GSuite documentation or forums.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they were using Outlook and messages are stored as *.pst files...

1. Setup IMAP access in the Gmail account and connect it to Outlook:  [Instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=637210465806358534-1609734036&hl=en&rd=1)
2. In Outlook, open the old Outlook Data (pst) File: [How to](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-and-close-outlook-data-files-pst-381b776d-7511-45a0-953a-0935c79d24f2)
3. In Outlook favorites bar, both the old and new accounts inboxes, sent items will be visible.  Copy / paste or drag and drop old messages in to new accounts location.  Instead of doing it manually, it is also possible for Outlook to automatically import / export, but I prefer doing the first way..
4. Disable IMAP access in the G-Suite / Gmail account if it is not needed.